# Installing ROS on 12.04 or 12.10

Tags: 12.04, compatibility

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 installed on my machine and I want to install ROS

I had a discussion with a friend who told me that it would be better to use Ubuntu 11.10 for ROS.

I am a new Ubuntu and ROS and would like to understand is my friend correct?  Can ROS run successfully on my 12.04/12.10 machine or do I need to install 11.10?

Comment: Are you talking about this software: http://www.ros.org/ ? It might help to explain this a bit in your question

Comment: Yes. I am talking about that software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its best to ask this @ ros.org as it depends which version of ROS you want to install.
Diff ROS versions run on specific ubuntu versions only.

Electric works best on 11.10

However, I would recommend installing 12.10 and then installing latest version of ROS. i.e, simply follow the instructions from : http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu for 12.10

(I didn't checked Hydra and 13.04)

Don't consider extended support of 12.04 as its best to keep up with the updates of ROS community.

Hope this helps